# Natural Neighbour to create DEM QGIS Hannover

Tags: qgis, error

I tried converting shapefile elevation coordinates using natural neighbour to create a DEM however I got the following error:

> The following layers were not correctly generated.
>
> C:/Users/stuar/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_eNJUbl/16ed8df2fe0e4bcfa26ec99fd0696461/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
> C:/Users/stuar/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_eNJUbl/5200f53077624943ac64aa1b4ef0a1c3/TARGET_OUT_GRID.sdat
>
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
> more information about the execution of the algorithm.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, what does the "log messages panel" say? Also, please add some details about the tool you used and the input data.

Comment: Hi Taras, 
       below is the error command any advice would be great!         
             Error: grid: memory allocation failed [-730.25mb]
             Error: executing tool [Natural Neighbour]

Comment: the input data was elevation point data which was in CSV format and i converted it to ESRI shapefile. The tool was natural neighbour from the SAGA dropdown processing list

Comment: Have you checked file paths for special characters? Can you provide example data and a screenshot of you points?

Comment: think i solved it...appeared to be a memory issue as I was saving to a hard drive!! thanks for your quick responses